# chrome extension for selecting a text and sending it for google search?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to develop a simple chrome extension in which i want to select a text from any web page and after clicking on a button it must search text in google.
I am new to extension. Right now i am able to select the text. But i can not able to google it. My code is as below.

Manifest.json

```
    {
 "name": "Selected Text",
 "version": "0.1",
 "description": "Selected Text",
 "manifest_version": 2,
 "browser_action": {
   "default_title": "Selected Text",
   "default_icon": "icon.PNG",
   "default_popup": "popup.html" 
 },
 "permissions": [
   "tabs",
   "<all_urls>"
 ],
 "content_scripts": [
   {
     "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
     "js": ["popup.js"]
   }
 ]
}
```

popup.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="popup.js"></script>
    <style>
      body { width: 300px; }
      textarea { width: 250px; height: 100px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="text"> </textarea>
    <button id="Hindi" button onclick="Hindi Meaning">Hindi Meaning</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

popup.js

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript( {
    code: "window.getSelection().toString();"
    }, function(selection) {

      console.log(selection[0]);
      if(selection[0].length > 0){
        document.getElementById("text").value = selection[0];
      }
});
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  chrome.tabs.sendRequest(tab.id, {method: "getSelection"}, function(response) {
    var selectedText = document.getElementById("text").value = selection[0];
    chrome.tabs.create({url: 'http://google.com?q=' + selectedText});
  });
});
```

Comment: The content script must be a different file because it runs in a different page - the popup is a separate window with its own page. The content script should have a message listener where you'll have to actually get the selected text.

Comment: If you are going to be opening a Google search in another tab, your users may find this more familiar if you use a context menu selection to perform this function rather than a button in a popup. However, if it's your intent to open the tab without displaying it to the user, grab the results and then display them in your popup, that might be more consistent with this UI flow.